# How does one call a promise function several times asynchronously to fill an array with a given number of values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise

I have a promise function which successfully can return a random integer between a min and max value.

```
const getRandomValue = (min = 0, max = 1) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    let randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    resolve(randomInteger);
  });
};
```

I am trying to asychronously fill an array using this promise function, with 4 random integers.

The chronology of the calls is a challenge for me and I am brand new to this type of programming. Below is what I have been trying to get to work without success.

```
  const getFourRandomValues = (min, max) => {
    let randomIntegerArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      getRandomValue(20,30).then(x => console.log(x));
      getRandomValue(20,30).then(x => {
        randomIntegerArray.push(x)
      });
    }
    return randomIntegerArray;
  };

console.log(getFourRandomValues());
```

As you experienced programers surely know, it yields:

```
[]
22
29
25
21
```

All help is much appreciated

Comment: "*I have a promise to create a random integer*" - is this your actual code? If it's not just a toy example: Do not use promises for stuff that is actually synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, that if you execute asynchronous operations, the will be resolved or rejected only after your synchronous code, that's why in your example you get an empty array. You can easily avoid it using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), I recommend it for your case because you're using multiple asynchronous calls.

The logic is the following:

1. Push every asynchronous call into array.
2. Call `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)`
3. Handle the result via `.then()` block (inside `then` you have an access to the result of every call if each of them was resolved successfully)

Here is an example:

```js
const getRandomValue = (min = 0, max = 1) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    let randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    resolve(randomInteger);
  });
};

const getFourRandomValues = (min, max) => {
  let promises = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    promises.push(getRandomValue(20,30));
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

getFourRandomValues()
  .then(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: thanks very much for your suggestion, it is a very clean solution and I appreciate your comments explaining that promises only run after all synchronous script - that helped tremendously

Answer (score 0):

Your `getFourRandomValues` method is doing an async operation. Since then, it should be an async function as well. The `[]` is returned in your console because you are trying to output the array before the promises inside it has been resolved.

To fix it, you can change `getFourRandomValues` method to return a promise, that will be resolved when the array is ready:

```
const getFourRandomValues = async(min, max) => {
let randomIntegerArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    const randomValue = await getRandomValue(20,30);
    randomIntegerArray.push(randomValue)
}
return randomIntegerArray;
```

};

```
getFourRandomValues().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

In this example I used [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for better code readability.

Comment: many thanks for your help and clear description of my logic error. It seems quite obvious now

Comment: Looks that there is no guaranty that the array would be ready when the promise returned by `getFourRandomValues` is resolved. I'm missing something?

Comment: This is a horrible answer that doesn't even work (it outputs the expected result only because of sheer luck with sequencing callbacks on synchronously resolved promises - it breaks apart if you put a timeout in `getRandomValue`).